# How can I access a Mule message through Ruby?

Tags: ruby, jruby, mule

With Mule scripting, I am able to access a Mule Message in Groovy, JavaScript and Jython via a `message` variable. With JRuby I cannot:

```
undefined local variable or method `message' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Neither the Mule docs or the Internets have anything to say on this. How can I access the message from Ruby?

**Code**

```
<scripting:transformer name="SetData" doc:name="Set Data">
    <scripting:script engine="jruby">
        <scripting:text><![CDATA[File.open('/tmp/foo', 'w') { |f| f.puts message.payload }]]></scripting:text>
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

Comment: I am using the latest Mule Studio version, which is 1.1.0. It comes with JRuby 1.0 and JRuby Engine 1.1.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Mule config"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule bound variables end up in the global scope, so you need to refer them with `$name`.

In your case:

```
<scripting:transformer name="SetData" doc:name="Set Data">
    <scripting:script engine="jruby">
        <scripting:text><![CDATA[
           File.open('/tmp/foo', 'w') { |f| f.puts $message.payload }
        ]]></scripting:text>
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

Note that if you only need the message payload, you'd rather use `$payload` instead of `$message.payload`.

Also your transformer looks more like a component IMO: it acts on the data (writes to file) instead of transforming it. It doesn't even have a clear return value (you sure don't want to process the return of `File.open` in Mule. So a `scripting:component` would be more in order here.

Finally, if all you need to do is write to file, you can use a [File outbound endpoint from Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/File+Transport+Reference) that does just that.